# How to pass values to a Python executable from a config file

Tags: python, py2exe

I have created a Python executable using Py2exe. My python script pick values from a config file,but when i compile the script as an executable the values are hardcoded. Is there a way where i can still use my config file to feed values to my executable.

MyPythonScript

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_name("UserName").send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_name("Password").send_keys(password)
```

Myconfigfile

```
url = 'http://testurl'
username = 'testdata'
password = 'testdata'
```

Comment: Please show the part of the code where you read the configuration file.

Comment: I am just importing the Config file using the command   from config import *.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not obvious how you read the username and password from the config file.

In addition to that, may I suggest you to use any third-party to parse your configuration file, for example, [configobj](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/configobj.html) and [configparser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/configparser.html) modules.

### How to do that?

Assuming that you specify the path to the configuration file, when you run the execution file in the following way:

```
my_script.exe c:\Myconfigfile.txt
```

and assuming the configuration file looks like this:

```
[login]
username = user01
password = 123456
```

These are two examples of how to do that:

#### The ConfigParser way

```
import sys, ConfigParser

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "missing configuration file path"

config_path = sys.argv[1]
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.readfp(open(config_path))
print config.get('login', 'username'), config.get('login', 'password')
```

#### The not so recommended way

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print "missing configuration file path"

config_path = sys.argv[1]
config_hash = {}
with open(config_path, 'r') as config_stream:
    lines = config_stream.readlines()
for line in lines:
    key_value = line.split('=')
    # skip lines that are not in the "key = value" format
    if len(key_value) != 2:
        continue
    config_hash[key_value[0].strip()] = key_value[1].strip()

print config_hash['username'], config_hash['password']
```

Comment: why do you roll your own config parser when recommending `configobj`? And what is wrong with the standard library `configparser`?

Comment: @knitti, I was giving an example and implicating that using a third-party for parsing configuration file is the best way to do that. I haven't used `configparser`, so I cannot recommend it. I will add it to the post, though. ;)

Comment: Thank you for the solution schlezzz. I think your reply is close to what i wanted.